# One EBJ project include another EJB project, then javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException

Tags: java, glassfish, ejb

I have deployed an EJB project (named A, having an ejb and an war modules) on my server (glassfish 3.0 on Redhat). Then my another EJB project (named B) needs to use functions of A's xxx-ejb module, so I included A's ejb module. While I deployed B on server, exceptions came:

```
Exception while invoking class org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer load method
java.lang.RuntimeException: EJB Container initialization error
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:197)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbDeployer.load(EjbDeployer.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.load(ModuleInfo.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:216)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:338)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
    at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.LocalDeploymentFacility$LocalDFCommandRunner.run(LocalDeploymentFacility.java:138)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.client.AbstractDeploymentFacility.deploy(AbstractDeploymentFacility.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.DeployUtil.invokeDeploymentFacility(DeployUtil.java:89)
    at org.glassfish.admingui.common.util.DeployUtil.deploy(DeployUtil.java:66)
    at org.glassfish.admingui.common.handlers.DeploymentHandler.deploy(DeploymentHandler.java:186)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.handler.Handler.invoke(Handler.java:442)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:420)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.descriptors.LayoutElementBase.dispatchHandlers(LayoutElementBase.java:394)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.invokeCommandHandlers(CommandActionListener.java:150)
    at com.sun.jsftemplating.layout.event.CommandActionListener.processAction(CommandActionListener.java:98)
    at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:772)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.component.WebuiCommand.broadcast(WebuiCommand.java:166)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:775)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1267)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.sun.webui.jsf.util.UploadFilter.doFilter(UploadFilter.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:325)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:226)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:239)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while binding JNDI name maintree.util.GetHourlyTrendRemote for EJB : GetHourlyTrend
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeHome(BaseContainer.java:1530)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatelessSessionContainer.initializeHome(StatelessSessionContainer.java:197)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.ContainerFactoryImpl.createContainer(ContainerFactoryImpl.java:161)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.startup.EjbApplication.loadContainers(EjbApplication.java:207)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: Use rebind to override
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.doBindOrRebind(TransientContext.java:275)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext.bind(TransientContext.java:214)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContextProviderImpl.bind(SerialContextProviderImpl.java:79)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.bind(LocalSerialContextProviderImpl.java:81)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.bind(SerialContext.java:586)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.bind(SerialContext.java:602)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(InitialContext.java:421)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.publishObject(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:206)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.publishObject(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:187)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer$JndiInfo.publish(BaseContainer.java:5533)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.initializeHome(BaseContainer.java:1515)
    ... 69 more
```

Thus the problem should be: how can I deploy the same EJB modules on a same glassfish server twice. Or how can I let B use A's ejb module without including it explicitly?

Thanks a lot,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not include EJBs of project A to Project B. You should only include Remote classes of Project A.

Comment: Thanks JSS: but I cannot even new an instance, if I don't include project A. Where should project B find those declarations?

Comment: @Peter -There are 2 ways of sorting this issue: 1. In IDE you include the project A but when you create ear B then, only include Remote classes of Proj A. 2. create a Remote classes jar file of Project A and include that in IDE and also include in your ear. Hope that helps!

Comment: @JSS Thanks. Is there a third way? I create an app-client, which wraps all functions of A's project B needs. Then B only includes this app-client instead of ejb module. Does this way work?

Comment: @Peter - there may be endless ways but I would stick with creating a jar file of Project-A (containing Remote and other util classes) and including that in IDE and distribute with Project-B.